# C5208 and LNK2001&LNK2019

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-errors, typedef, visual-studio-2022

```
typedef struct {
    float b_xpos;
    float b_ypos;
    float b_xVel;
    float b_yVel;
    float f_xpos;
    float f_ypos;
    bool _flameOn = false;
    bool _isTrailing = false;
    float tb1_xpos;
    float tb1_ypos;
    float tb2_xpos;
    float tb2_ypos;
}ballData;
```

In ball class:

```
ballData* data = new ballData();
```

I want to write a game on visual studio 2022.And I have a problem. This is the part that compiler shows error. I don't know why is this code wrong. I have tried to add a name after struct like this.

```
typedef struct ya{
    float b_xpos;
    float b_ypos;
    float b_xVel;
    float b_yVel;
    float f_xpos;
    float f_ypos;
    bool _flameOn = false;
    bool _isTrailing = false;
    float tb1_xpos;
    float tb1_ypos;
    float tb2_xpos;
    float tb2_ypos;
}ballData;
```

but it's still wrong. How can I fix this? This is the code I copied from github.
https://github.com/sj602/PikachuVolleyball?fbclid=IwAR3HGGvkJbhFWZs249D8jvxePwt2yjQk0HUzEYZ8Cg1cNEPaOvFXJvy91J4
When I change to simpler c++ syntax like this

```
struct ballData {
    float b_xpos;
    float b_ypos;
    float b_xVel;
    float b_yVel;
    float f_xpos;
    float f_ypos;
    bool _flameOn = false;
    bool _isTrailing = false;
    float tb1_xpos;
    float tb1_ypos;
    float tb2_xpos;
    float tb2_ypos;
};
```

the new errors show like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9Dj6.png)
Can someone help me?

Comment: Please show a [mre] including the full compiler output

Comment: Strange story, C5208 is AFAIK warning in C++17 mode ... error with about same text in C++20 mode is C7626.

Comment: Basically it's a warning that you're using c++ in your c style struct definition: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c5208?view=msvc-170 use the simpler c++ syntax and the error/warning will go away

Comment: Do not use `typedef struct { ... } blah` in C++. Use `struct blah { ... }` instead. *This does not necessarily apply if you need compatibility with C, but your struct is not compatible anyway*